# Crear tabla en con datos de servidor SQL - Error de conexión

Tags: c#, html, sql-server

Estoy intentando crear una tabla en mi pagina web con datos que hay en mi servidor SQL pero estoy teniendo un fallo en la conexión. Por ahora esto es lo que tengo:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            //Populating a DataTable from database.
            DataTable dt = this.GetData();

            //Building an HTML string.
            StringBuilder html = new StringBuilder();

            //Table start.
            html.Append("<table border = '1'>");

            //Building the Header row.
            html.Append("<tr>");
            foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
            {
                html.Append("<th>");
                html.Append(column.ColumnName);
                html.Append("</th>");
            }
            html.Append("</tr>");

            //Building the Data rows.
            foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
            {
                html.Append("<tr>");
                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                {
                    html.Append("<td>");
                    html.Append(row[column.ColumnName]);
                    html.Append("</td>");
                }
                html.Append("</tr>");
            }

            //Table end.
            html.Append("</table>");

            //Append the HTML string to Placeholder.
            PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(new Literal { Text = html.ToString() });
        }
    }

    private DataTable GetData()
    {

        string webAppConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["webAppConnString"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(webAppConnString))
        {
            con.Open();
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT project_ID, user, date_time, projectAction, Comments FROM history;"))
            {
                using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Este es el error:

> Error relacionado con la red o específico de la instancia mientras se establecía una conexión con el servidor SQL Server. No se encontró el servidor o éste no estaba accesible. Compruebe que el nombre de la instancia es correcto y que SQL Server está configurado para admitir conexiones remotas.

Pero no lo comprendo ya que en la pagina web tengo muchos otros métodos donde hay que buscar información en el servidor y no he tenido este problema. ¿O habría alguna otra manera de crear una tabla?

Muchas gracias de antemano.

Comment: Lo primero, debes depurar la aplicación y comprobar que obtienes en `webAppConnString`, por si estuvieras recibiendo una cadena de conexión errónea.

Comment: El problema no es el código sino la conexión que estás intentando crear. Verifica que todos los parámetros sean correctos, que tengas permisos (incluyendo si hay un firewall activo) o incluso si el usuario existe en la base de datos.

Comment: Tu problema esta en la cadena de conexion. Verificala que este correcta o que tengas acceso al server desde tu aplicacion.